# How can I get the first day of next month using Angular and Moment

Tags: angular, momentjs

We have a problem regarding the generated logs on our application. And the solution is we need to get the first day of the next month even if the selected day is on the middle of the month.

Tried to read docs on Moment but I couldn't found any possible solution.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var start_date = new Date(); //Wed Jun 05 2019 13:23:06 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)

console.log(start_date);

start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() - 365); //1496640186958

console.log(start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() - 365)); //Monday, June 5, 2017 1:23:06.958 PM GMT+08:00
// this output should be July 1, 2017, how can I get the first day of next month here?

start_date = customizeDate.formatDateToString(start_date);
var end_date = dateRange.endDate;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this with your custom format

```
const startOfNextMonth = moment().add(1, 'M').startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
```

```js
const startOfNextMonth = moment().add(1, 'M').startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
console.log(startOfNextMonth);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Vanilla JavaScript. Do note that I have added the if statement to check if the month of the current Date is December. This is to prevent any issues whereby the month will 'overflow' to 12.

```js
const today = new Date(); 
let next;
if (today.getMonth() === 11) {
  next = new Date(today.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);
} else {
    next = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 1);
}

console.log(next);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve it using this chain of function:

```
console.log(moment(1496640186958).add(1, 'months').startOf('month').format('ll'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible approach, creating a new date object then adding 1 to the month and finally setting the day to the 1st:

```
start_date = new Date(start_date.getFullYear(), start_date.getMonth() + 1, 1);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7c29yd)